# Comparing three dynamic ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare Workbooks pkws (A Column), tmpws (A Column), and fdws (B Column).

Data looks like “123456789”.  If something matches, the macro should highlight a row in pkws Workbook.

Here is my code, which works for two workbooks, but not for three. I have tried to enter one more variable (comparing pkws and fdws).

```
If StrComp(Trim(range1.Text), Trim(range2.Text), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
```

```vb
Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range, n As Long, m As Long
For n = 1 To pkws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set range1 = pkws.Range("A" & n)
    For m = 1 To tmpws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set range2 = tmpws.Range("A" & m)
        If StrComp(Trim(range1.Text), Trim(range2.Text), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            range1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End If
        Set range2 = Nothing
    Next m
    Set range1 = Nothing
Next n
```

Comment: `If StrComp(Trim(range1.Text), Trim(range2.Text), vbTextCompare) = 0  And StrComp(Trim(range1.Text), Trim(range3.Text), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then`

Comment: Tim Williams, thank you ! I cannot test this part - trying to use it , but macro is started to be frozen until I end the task manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nested loop approach will be very slow, so something like this might be a better method:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range, range3 As Range, c As Range
    Dim m1, m2, v

    Set range1 = pkws.Range("A1:A" & pkws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set range2 = tmpws.Range("A1:A" & tmpws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set range3 = fdws.Range("A1:A" & fdws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<<EDIT

    For Each c In range1.Cells
        v = c.Text
        'look for matches in the other sheets
        m1 = Application.Match(v, range2, 0)
        m2 = Application.Match(v, range3, 0)

        If Not IsError(m1) And Not IsError(m2) Then
            'got two matches...
            c.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for a reply! I have tried it, and have got an error "Invalid procedure call or argument". and this spot was highlighted: `m2 = Application.Match(v, range3, 0)`